# jQuery .hide() element not working

Tags: jquery, hide

I am trying to do a simple `.hide()` with jQuery but it's not working for some reason. I tried it with jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/j0a2zbyb/1/) but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML code

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".error").hide();

        });
    </script>
```

CSS code

```
.error{
width: 300px;
height: auto;
background-color: #FF6C6C;
border: solid 2px #000;
}
```

Comment: The document.ready function can't be prevented

Comment: It can but the _default_ action can’t really be prevented (or preventing has no effect). It’s just that the `e` is _not an event_ and thus cannot be prevented!

Comment: It really can't, and `e` is jQuery so you can do `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...` to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ready` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler is not called with an [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) like other event handlers. It's called with a reference to the jQuery object (intended to be used when the [`noConflict` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) has been used).

When you try to call [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the value passed to the function, you get an error becase there is no such method in that object.

If you avoid the `preventDefault` call, it works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".error").hide();
});
```

Side note: An alternative to using `hide` in the `ready` event would be to use `display:none;` in the CSS. That way there is no risk that the element would be visible for a short moment while the page loads, as the CSS ensures that it's invisible as soon as it is created.

Answer (score 0):

Do not prevent default:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e){

        $(".error").hide();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-thinking it. Try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".error").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".error").hide();
});
```

```css
.error{
width: 300px;
height: auto;
background-color: #FF6C6C;
border: solid 2px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="error"> error</div>
<div class="noerror"> noerror</div>
```